# Prove for every $n \geq 2$ : $1!+2!+...+n! < \frac{(n+1)!}{n-1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$1!+2!+...+n! < \frac{(n+1)!}{n-1}$

I tried to solve it with induction,

for $n = 2$ it holds,  $1!+2! < \frac{6}{1}$.

so by using induction step I have to prove:

$\frac{(n+1)!}{n-1} + (n+1)! < \frac{(n+2)!}{n}$

but I just don't know how. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does **n \geg 2** means?

Comment: It means $n \geq 2$

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, it's supposed to be *greater or equal* to.

Comment: @badatmath Big simplification you can make: $(n+1)!$ is always nonzero, so divide both sides by it. This should make things much simpler. Also note that you should be able to replace the strict inequality you've given with an inclusive one: switch $<$ to $\leq.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan Ok so I divided by $(n+1)!$ and I ended up with $n^{2} < n^{2}+n-2$, which doesn't hold for $n=2$. So I assume there's a mistake and there should be inclusive inequality like you just noted. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @badatmath This is equivalent to a step that I saw while looking over the problem, so you've likely proceeded correctly. The reason you can use the inclusive inequality is that if we have that $1! + 2! + \ldots + n! < \frac{(n+1)!}{n-1},$ then we have $1! + 2! + \ldots (n+1)! < \frac{(n+1)!}{n-1} + (n+1)!,$ so if $\frac{(n+1)!}{n-1} + (n+1)! = \frac{(n+2)!}{n}$ then we still have $1! + 2! + \ldots (n+1)! < \frac{(n+2)!}{n}.$ Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments, the OP explains they are stuck on the fact that the strict inequality $n^2\lt n^2+n-2$, which is what you get after simplifying the inequality ${(n+1)!\over n-1}+(n+1)!\lt{(n+2)!\over n}$, does not hold for $n=2$. There's a simple way to fix this: Move the strict inequality to where it occurs in the induction hypothesis, and prove the second, *non*-strict inequality in

$$1!+2!+\cdots+n!+(n+1)!\lt{(n+1)!\over n-1}+(n+1)!\le{(n+2)!\over n}$$

(Alternatively, one could check the first *two* base cases, and then begin the induction at $n=3$.)

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense.